# Excel Formula for importing data from several sheets

Tags: excel, import, excel-formula, vba

I have a massive excel document with multiple sheets I need help importing data with from one sheet to another.

In sheet 1 there is a list of entities and what the affiliation's of those entities are. On sheet 2 there is the same list of entities and column name describing each affliction. My goal is to have a formula which looks at each affiliation's and marks a Yes  where the Colum name representing the affliction is. 
An example of what I mean is:

There is one sheet (sheet 1) which has a column named "Student", and another column next to it named "Favorite color" there are about 4000 (rows) student's information. Some students might have more then one favorite color, but in that case there are 2 entries of the student in the sheet. On another sheet(sheet 2) there is the same column "Student" but there are several columns with each color of the rainbow (Red, Blue, Green etc) these columns have to be marked with a yes or a no. **I need to read back into sheet 1 and mark a yes on the 2nd sheet depending on the color described on sheet one.**

Answer (score 1):

A `VLOOKUP` will not suffice when the student can have two "favourite colours". Instead, assuming the same sheet format as @Nelly27281, you can use a COUNTIFS in the following way:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!$B:$B,B$1)>0,"YES","NO")
```

This counts the number of instances in `Sheet1` where Column A contains the student *and* Column B contains the colour. If it's greater than 0, we associate the student with the colour.

EDIT: sorry, I've assumed here that Column A of `Sheet2` contains a list of the students without any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula that you can use. Place the formula in cell B2 and drag it across the columns and rows that you want to cover:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)=B$1,"YES","")
```

Assuming your data are presented like:

[image]